# shutdown -m \\crashbox -r -t 03 windows7

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, remote-access

As a server administrator i can shutdown the system on network with

shutdown -m \crashbox -r -t 03

i have one PC on network with windows7 and this pc is also not part of domain but i also have its IP and name.

when i try to execute this command i got message

Access denied

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the "My Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\forceguest" key is set to "0" on the Windows 7 machine.

You may want to look into the PSTools utlity called [PSShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) which is more powerful and gives you more options.